# Why does one code work, but the other doesn't?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out why one code works, but the other doesn't. The problem is that in the first code, the website doesn't react to any keyboard presses, while in the last code it does work. Mouse clicks work in both codes. The only difference in the coding is the very first for statement. But I thought this for statement only applied to the click event, and has nothing to do with keyboard events?

Code that doesn't work:

```
for (var i = 0; 1 < document.querySelectorAll(".drum").length; i++) {

  document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

    var buttonInnerHTML = this.innerHTML;

    makeSound(buttonInnerHTML);


  });
}


document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {

  makeSound(event.key);


});

function makeSound(key) {

  switch (key) {
    case "w":
      var tom1 = new Audio("sounds/tom-1.mp3");
      tom1.play();
      break;

    case "a":
      var tom2 = new Audio("sounds/tom-2.mp3");
      tom2.play();
      break;

    case "s":
      var tom3 = new Audio("sounds/tom-3.mp3");
      tom3.play();
      break;

    case "d":
      var tom4 = new Audio("sounds/tom-4.mp3");
      tom4.play();
      break;

    case "j":
      var snare = new Audio("sounds/snare.mp3");
      snare.play();
      break;

    case "k":
      var crash = new Audio("sounds/crash.mp3");
      crash.play();
      break;

    case "l":
      var kick = new Audio("sounds/kick-bass.mp3");
      kick.play();
      break;

    default: console.log(key);

  }

}
```

Code that does work:

```
var numberOfDrumButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".drum").length;

for (var i = 0; i < numberOfDrumButtons; i++) {

  document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

    var buttonInnerHTML = this.innerHTML;

    makeSound(buttonInnerHTML);


  });

}

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {

  makeSound(event.key);


});


function makeSound(key) {

  switch (key) {
    case "w":
      var tom1 = new Audio("sounds/tom-1.mp3");
      tom1.play();
      break;

    case "a":
      var tom2 = new Audio("sounds/tom-2.mp3");
      tom2.play();
      break;

    case "s":
      var tom3 = new Audio('sounds/tom-3.mp3');
      tom3.play();
      break;

    case "d":
      var tom4 = new Audio('sounds/tom-4.mp3');
      tom4.play();
      break;

    case "j":
      var snare = new Audio('sounds/snare.mp3');
      snare.play();
      break;

    case "k":
      var crash = new Audio('sounds/crash.mp3');
      crash.play();
      break;

    case "l":
      var kick = new Audio('sounds/kick-bass.mp3');
      kick.play();
      break;


    default: console.log(key);

  }
}
```

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i <` not `for (var i = 0; 1 <`

Comment: Thanks for noticing, i've been scrutinizing my code and couldn't see anything anymore. But I still don't understand why that affects the event listener for keydown?

Comment: Because event is not added at all in that wrong loop you made, learn how loops work: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: @ikiK Nice, if we ever run out of salt in the seas we can just ask you for more.

Comment: @JavaScript I'm available anytime.

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop in the first code block doesn't work because you're comparing **1 with document.querySelectorAll(".drum").length**

```
for (var i = 0; 1 < document.querySelectorAll(".drum").length; i++) {
//Logic
}
```

**What it should be:**

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll(".drum").length; i++) {
//Logic
}
```

Also, I recommend you use let & const instead of var for declaring variables. Goodluck!